# Style of table view like on app LiveScore

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to find an open source for style of table view which is shown on app LiveScore (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/livescore/id356928178?mt=8), mean current header is fixed and only replaced by the next header when we scroll out all lines of current section. I tried to search but not success. Could anyone tell me one?

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: this is a combination of table section,custom Cell and resized cell height and section height.

Comment: @NitinGohel Yes, I see. However, I want to find an open source for research purpose. I remember that there are a kind of open source on Github, have seen on Github trending, but cannot retrieve its name, then I can't search.

Comment: check here it is lots of table view examples hope one of helps to you. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tableview

Comment: @NitinGohel Thank you, also tried but very time consuming and can't find. Hope someone knows exactly its name :).

Comment: Split your data into sections and add header views to each of those sections.  The header will stick to the top until the next section.  This is default behavior, no open source or hacking necessary.

Comment: @Logan Just double check, you are right, my mistake. So sorry, thank you!